# Visual Studio Large Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've got a solution for my webapplication with almost 12 projects and 3 websites.
There are some projects that I use for multiple websites like MyProject.BE / MyProject.BLL / MyProject.DAL / MyProject.Controls projects.

My question is, is it good to have multiple projects for BE/BLL/DAL/Controls, of is it better to create 1 project with folders for the BE/BLL/DAL layers?

Comment: If you merge them into one, how are you going to reference it in others, the current one seems fine but is it the actual issue/problem ?

Comment: *almost 12 projects* - i.e. 11 projects?

Comment: Multiple projects is perfectly fine. I've worked on solutions with ~60 projects.

Comment: visual studio is very slow on building my projects, that's why I thought it might be better to have 1 project with subfolders instead of the projects

Comment: @Leon Cullens ... what was the performance of VS2010?

Comment: @Ruutert Well, the performance was slightly lower, but it didn't notice substantial differences. It's mostly the start-up time of VS that's slow, but usually you'll start VS only once and then have it open for the rest of the day.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but having more code in fewer projects won't make your build faster.

Comment: Currently working with 28projects in solution without any problems. PC: SSD, i5, 8G ram. Also i like to disable build in configuration manager projects which I change rarely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question of "large" is a relative one. In software development it is mostly a question of how good your PC is. If you can compile and run 100 projects in 1 second then 100 projects in a solution is "small". So it is really a question of what works for you.

My current work solution has about 130 projects in it. Yep, we could break it out but we have got some impressive boxes that can handle this so the cost of having 130 projects is moderate to low and advantages are bigger that the costs.

Having all of the projects in one solution is the go if you can compile, run, & test them all quickly. Darn ... that then starts the conversation onto what is "quick" and that is a style question. If you compile and run tests often (every minute or faster) then quick is seconds. If you compile and run every hour or so then minutes would be okay.

Answer: "Do what works for you".

Note: Consider solution folders.

Comment: My last company had well over 350 projects within one solution.  Most of the projects were class libraries which were referenced within another project.  Although the solution had 350 projects this doesn't mean to say that this was a large solution.  It was a large solution due to the complexity and amount of code each project had.  As Rob Smyth said it's all relative.  We found that building the entire solution was dangerous so we only built the projects we had to. I.E. we only built the projects we had made changes to.

Comment: +1 for the help figuring out what a "large" solution could be, also +1 for the folder use suggestion.

Comment: by "good PC" are you primarily talking about RAM (size & speed)? or is HDD access speed more important?

Comment: Hi Matthew. I think your asking what is the primary issue to speed up a computer. If so ... I cannot answer that. If your concerned about your PC's performance then monitor memory usage, CPU, etc and fix whichever is at/near its limits. From my experience memory usage should be <50%, total CPU should typically be < 20%. But that is outside by skill set. FYI: The fast machines I referred to had (from memory) 32GB RAM, two SDDs (one for OS, the other for data), and I7 CPUs. If you need to justify cost you need to record time compiling etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is indeed better to have multiple projects.  If, for instance you need to build a WinForms UI that will use some of the existing classes in your BE and DAL layers all you need to do is reference those projects from the WinForms project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understoodyour question, you are referring to how-to-organize-a-solution rather than how-do-I-make-compiling-the-code faster or how-to-make-VS-open-my-code-quicker, right?

If so, I would say, break down your classes within the solution into multiple projects with names that make it clear what purpose they have. You already started an approach like that with the "BE/BLL/DAL/Controls" example you gave.

Having designated project give you lots of flexibility for how your solution architecture. Think about how much your solution may grow over time and for how long it may live in future. Think about how you will deploy it to the end users and - more importantly - how you will deploy updates. All these considerations should influence your decision how far you will go into details.

Analyse your code and check if there is potential to apply time-proven design patterns like Single Responsibility pattern.

Is it a short-term short-lived tool that runs a few times during development and never again? Then it would not be worth much effort. Is it a tool or application that will need to be maintained a few years? Then go and make sue that the SRP pattern is carefully implemented.

I recommend this book by Microsoft Press: [Building Enterprise Applications with Windows Presentation Foundation and the Model View ViewModel Pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735650926)

This gives you some suggestions, recommendations and basics of how to build a good project structure.

Another suggestion of how a solution might be structured is in this SO thread: [Mvvm Applications And location of Business layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859965/mvvm-applications-and-location-of-business-layer)